# Typescript login function typing problems

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I am currently experiencing a problem with my login code, where it is supposed to take a username and password, find the corresponding hash in the database, compare them, sign a JWT and return it so that it can be sent back to the user:

```
async login(username, password): Promise<boolean | void> {
// TODO: Fix typing.
//  Types the return as void currently - should return object.
//  No return at all either, however console.log prints result - check SO when you have time
const dbPwdHash = await this.userRepository.createQueryBuilder('user')
  .select(['user.password', 'user.id'])
  .where('user.username = :username', {username})
  .getOne();
return compare(password, dbPwdHash.password)
  .then(
    (res) => {
      if (res) {
        return sign({ id: dbPwdHash.id }, this.privateKey, { algorithm: 'ES512' }, (err, token) => {
          if (err) {
            return {err};
          } else {
            console.log(token);
            return {data: token};
          }
        });
      }
    },
  )
  .catch(
    (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    },
  );
}
```

The type definitions type the returns for compare and sign (from `bcrypt` and `jsonwebtoken` respectively) are both void by default when using the asynchronous functions with the promise on the compare and the callback on the sign.

The biggest problem I am however experiencing is the fact that in the end nothing gets returned even though a `console.log` shows that the password is successfully compared and the JWT gets successfully signed.
I am sure it is a problem with the sign function as returning the res from the `.then()` in the compare works fine, however as soon as I add the sign codeblock, nothing returns. However, I'm not sure what exactly is causing that as well as how I'm supposed to respect the typing rules when compare returns `<boolean | void>` while sign returns `<string | void>` afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `JWT.sign()` with callback passed will execute it asynchronously - which is what you do, this means that the call will return `undefined` which is what you are returning.

You can either *Promisify* that call or call `JWT.sign` synchronously which will then be returned as Promise of a `compare(..).then(...)` block.

In order to 'Promisify' this callback your return statement would look something like this:

```
return compare(password, dbPwdHash.password)
        .then(
            (res) => {
                if (res) {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        sign({id: dbPwdHash.id}, this.privateKey, {algorithm: 'ES512'}, (err, token) => {
                            if (err) {
                                reject(err);
                            } else {
                                console.log(token);
                                resolve({data: token});
                            }

                        });
                    });
                }
                ;
            }
        )
        .catch(
            (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            },
        );
```

reference: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback

Comment: Won't executing JWT.sign synchronously affect thread performance even though it is inside the promise returned by compare if I understand right? Also, trying to promisify JWT.sign using .then doesn't work at all, since it claims that the .then is not  property of string

Comment: check this for how to convert callback to Promise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises

Comment: @WolfSkin - I have edited answer with sample on how to convert to promise - let me knwo if it works

Comment: Other than the fact that the typing is still broken (and I'll probably have to just ignore it), it works perfectly!

Comment: @WolfSkin - Great I suggest you edit your question a bit so that it's clear it's the issue with calling sign on jwt) - I assume more people would run into this problem, regardless of using typescript.